# XCode / iOS delay before Resources are available

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, cocos2d-x

I am using XCode 5.1.1 to build a multi-platform (Cocos2d-x) project. I am finding that there seems to be a delay before some of my resources are available to be loaded. For example if I try to access a file like this:

```
std::ifstream t(path);

if(!t) {
    std::cout << "Warning - no such file found" << std::endl;
}
```

...the file will just not be there sometimes. (By which I mean that it sometimes just does not appear to find the file.) If I delay the load for a second then it will be there. Also, if I insert a breakpoint and then resume execution the file will be there. It even seems to happen more often if I am running the application from the iOS springboard rather than debugging in XCode.

This is also happening with loading texture files in my project, using APIs in Cocos2d-x.

**EDIT** @LearnCocos2D suggested that I may be trying to load the files before the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching function is called. I didn't know about that requirement, but after examining my code I'm pretty sure everything is loaded after that. The textures that are not loading are created for children of a cocos2d::Scene that is created inside the AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() function (I started my project based on the HelloWorld example that comes with Cocos2d-x.)

The program flow is something like this:

```
AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()

//...

auto scene = GameScene::createScene();

//... create Sprites etc, but they never show on the screen :(
```

**EDIT** Ok, I fixed my problem. It turned out that I was totally wrong about the cause of the problem, and it was actually an initialisation problem that lead to undefined behaviour. However, @LearnCocos2D's comment about having to wait for applicationDidFinishLaunching() before Resources are available is a good tip.

Comment: "the file will just not be there sometimes" meaning what exactly? Do you get an error? Does it return nil? And where do you run this code? Perhaps this is in main() (as in: too early to access resource files) rather than in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching... or later methods.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - I was not aware that I could not access resources until after didFinishLaunching. That probably explains the ifstream example, but probably not the Cocos2d-x texture loading, which I'm certain is happening afterward. I'll edit my question with more detail.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - Hey, If you make your tip about waiting for didFinishLaunching an answer, I'll mark it as correct, since that did explain part of my problem.